# HttpClient 4 - What happened to MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm writing a swing application with HttpClient 4.

I followed the standard approach by passing a `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` to my shared `HttpClient` instance for now. But now I would like to be able to execute multiple requests/downloads at the same time...

I found some examples with `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` for `HttpClient 3.x` but can I use it for version 4.x ? If so how ? I tried it but without success...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 4.x, the equivalent is **Pooling connection manager**. You can read more details on its usage in section [Pooling connection manager here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html). I would also strongly suggest you to [read this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-users@hc.apache.org/msg02765.html) on their forum.

Comment: The Pooling connection manager link above is 404 now.

Comment: @PerryTew fixed it

Answer (score 1):

There's no indication in the javadoc that a `DefaultHttpClient` instance is thread-safe.

So, I think you should just create an `HttpClient` instance for each activity ... using a common/shared `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` instance.  That should allow you to reuse connections between `HttpClient` instances.  Just make sure that you don't shut down the connection manager.

The APIs are sufficiently different between version 3.x and 4.x that I'd be surprised if the examples for one were instructive for the other.